# Redirecting a registration link in logintoboggan

Tags: 7, users

I've got a register link and a log in link that is augmented by logintoboggan. All I want to do is redirect the register link from the user account form page to a new page I've just made. It seems very simple, but I can't find where the I can change the link. Any help would be amazing, thanks.

Comment: may be try Login Redirect Module: http://drupal.org/project/login_redirect

Comment: you also can have a look to rules module

Answer (score 0):

Use a [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to alter the *user/register* path and add your own *page callback* to it.

Comment: Thanks, karthik. I really just needed to find where the URL was, which was in the template folder, duh.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Work in progress for a Drupal 7 integration and collaboration between redirection-type modules:
>
> - [Path redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_redirect)
> - [Global redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect)
>
> Current features:
>
> - Common API for loading, saving, and deleting redirects.
> - Case-insensitive redirect matching with a hook to allow other modules to narrow-down the candidate redirects.
> - Redirect counter and last used timestamp, with automatic cleanup of inactive redirects.
> - Integration with Drupal's page cache to optimize redirects and performance.
> - Complete individual redirect access API.
> - [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) API integration.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it in your  template.php of active theme or custom module

```
 function YOURthemename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
      // this will give you a good idea of the page content and variables
      if(arg(0)=='user' && arg(1)=='register'){
              drupal_goto('newregisterpath');
      }
        if((arg(0)=='user' && arg(1)=='login') || if(arg(0)=='user' && arg(1)=='')){
         drupal_goto('newloginpath');
       }
    }
```

And further you have modules like **Path_redirect** etc already mentioned in the previous comments.

Hope it willhelp you!