# LoginToboggan redirect to the same page on Drupal-7

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I have a Drupal-7 website and I use LoginToboggan module for login.
Is there a way to override this module or change the settings, in order to redirect users to the same page after successful login, and not on the user's profile page?

Comment: Have look at [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16423/redirecting-a-registration-link-in-logintoboggan). It's similar to yours, and there are several good answers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, what did it was the Login Destination module!